# Change JSON formatting

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, facebook

The following two pages provide the same JSON object. Is it possible to have the Facebook Style JSON formatting for my rails application??

Desired formatting:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/19292868552
```

My Application formatting:

```
http://sframework.heroku.com/api/graphs
```

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ruby json library has a [pretty_generate](http://apidock.com/ruby/JSON/pretty_generate) function.

```
require 'json'
puts JSON.pretty_generate(fbJson)
```

Comment: def index
    file = open("https://graph.facebook.com/19292868552")
    @message = JSON.pretty_generate(file.read)
    respond_with(@message)
  end

Comment: this produces an error: 2011-06-30T17:38:04+00:00 app[web.1]: JSON::GeneratorError (only generation of JSON objects or arrays allowed):

Comment: @ntenisOT You may need to first parse the Facebook result into a json object with something like JSON.parse(file.read)

Comment: Yes mate. Thanks. That was the problem. Thanks again!:)